# Header + Content + Footer with a form that nests everything

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML that has a header, a scrollable content, and a footer and it works fine.

What I would like to add to this HTML is a form that wraps all three divs, the problem is that as soon as I wrap the divs with the  tag the layout breaks. any suggestions?

```
<head>
</head>

<style>
<!--
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

* html body {
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

div#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

div#content {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#footer {
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
-->
</style>

<body>
  <div id="header">header</div>

  <div id="content">
    bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br />
    bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br />
    bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla<br /> bla last<br />
  </div>

  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you .. your problem is with the `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` that you give to them.

When you wrap them in `<div>` you have to give that div `position` (relative for example). The absolute and fixed elements are related to the **closest positioned** element. In your case .. no matter you wrap them in 10 divs .. the closest positioned element stays the **BODY**.

Comment: The HTML I provided works fine, what doesn't work is that I want to have <body><form>... the divs ...</form></body> when adding the <form>  to the above HTML the layout breaks! how can I achieve this?